# How can I know when a new version is available in source control?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I've been relying on email alerts, but I don't like doing that. Is there an alert or notification or some other clue within Visual Studio itself to let me know I need to get latest?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TFVC, the source control explorer will show you on a file by file basis whether you have the latest version.

If you're using Team Rooms, the team room can be configured to display notifications whenever a user commits a change.

In general, it shouldn't matter too much -- just do a "get latest" a few times a day and resolve any conflicts that pop up.